# Change the date format in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I m trying to change the date format in phpmyadmin. I m unable to change the format I want to change the format to dd-mmm-yyyy. How can I change the date format. Please help me with it..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use phpMyAdmin's [browser transformations](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html) feature to do this.

- Go to the `Structure` page of the relevant table.
- Click on the `Change` hyperlink in the `Actions` column of the
  relavent date/datetime/timestamp column.
- Chose `Text/Plain: Dateformat` from the `Browser Transformation`
  dropdown.
- Insert `0,'%d-%b-%Y','local'` into the transformation options column.
- Save the changes and go back to `Browse` page.

From the documentation on `Text/Plain: Dateformat` transformation

> Displays a `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` or numeric unix timestamp column as formatted date. The first option is the offset (in hours) which will be added to the timestamp (default: 0). Use second option to specify a different date/time format string. Third option determines whether you want to see local date or UTC one (use `"local"` or `"utc"` strings) for that. According to that, date format has different value - for `"local"` see the documentation for PHP's `strftime()` function and for `"utc"` it is done using `gmdate()` function.

Comment: It shows date as 05-Sep-2019. How can I specify format for Time. I want to show it lke "05-Sep-2019 02:45 PM". how can I specify it?

Comment: You can't use the above answer to change your date format if it is in another format. First of all you need to insert in database as specified ( 0000-00-00). Then you can change its view in our own format through the above solution.

Answer (score 11):

<del>It's not possible as far as I know.</del> I stand corrected, see @Madhura Jayaratne's answer for how to change the date format using phpMyAdmin. However, if that's not available or you don't have permission, you can use the solution below to reformat it in PHP.

Let's say your $date_from_sql is set to 2014-03-23.

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_from_sql)); //date format
```

Now $date equals **23-03-2014**

Optionally you can wrap it in a function to use it throughout your application.

```
function fixdate($date) {
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
}

// When parsing data from the database:
$query = query("SELECT wrongdate FROM something")->result();
$date = fixdate($query->date);
```

Answer (score 1):

However, it's easy to change in PHP.

```
$myinput='2005/15/09'; $sqldate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($myinput)); echo $sqldate;
```

Now  09-15-2005.