# MySQL date format not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, date-format

In `phpmyadmin`, I would like to view a column with timestamp info formatted as `27 Oct 7:22`, which is easy to get in the console if I type:

```
select date_format(now(),'%e %b %H:%i')
```

However, the funny thing is that when I set in the column the 'Browser display information options' as 0,'%e %b %H:%i' it shows nothing, but it seems that any other options work, but not that combination.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Why are you using PHPMyAdmin for this?

Comment: I just want to browse my tables easily as they're shown by phpadmin, without having to write a select statement. Of course, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should try ,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), " %e %b %h:%s");
```

Comment: Thank you, Damini, but perhaps I didn't make myself understood... I am doing what @MadhuraJayaratne suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827579/change-the-date-format-in-phpmyadmin) The `date_format` that I use in the Select statement is to show it works when I use it in the phpmyadmin console, but if I include it in the column display formatting options, it does not, but for some reason, other combinations I've tested do work, and I don't know if it is a bug

Answer (score 0):

It's a little odd that it isn't showing you any output at all, although it may be caused because your syntax is a [bit off](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php): there is no `%i` variable here; you probably meant `%M` instead. When I use the transformation setting `0,%e %b %H:%M`, I get the expected output.

[image: Output transformation options]

[image: Transformed browser view]

While not exactly intuitive, the syntax for this (and other transformations) are visible by following the linked text "Browser display transformation;" this information is also available as a tool tip provided when hovering over the dropdown:

[image: Dropdown tooltip]

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work! My problem is that I used the manuals for Mysql / MariaDB for DATE_FORMAT ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)) and it states very clearly that %i is for minutes, (and %M for the month's name!) so I would love to know where you've got the correct info from! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing; it's not exactly intuitive, but there are a link and a tool tip available with some additional information; I've improved my answer above with that information. I wonder how phpMyAdmin can present this information in a more user-friendly way.